# Replacing a threshold check with Nan values in Pandas with where condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I am trying to fill in NAN values in the dataframe where the threshold level is met. But instead NAN in the output am getting nulls instead in the output.

My code mentioned below:

```
import numpy as np

def a(df):
    df.loc[df['col1']>18.9,['col1']] = np.nan
    return df
```

Input

```
col1
18.50
18.92
```

Output

```
col1
18.50
null
```

expected output

```
col1
18.50
NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ali":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],"mali":[4,2,6,4,5,6,10]})
df["tresholholded"] = np.where(df.ali<df.mali,np.nan,df.ali)
df
#output
    ali mali tresholholded
0   1   4   NaN
1   2   2   2.0
2   3   6   NaN
3   4   4   4.0
4   5   5   5.0
5   6   6   6.0
6   7   10  NaN
```

`np.where` you can select the `conditions` that you want in the `first` argument, then the `second` argument you place the `IF TRUE` and for the last argument you place the `ELSE`.

```
df["tresholholded"] = np.where(df.ali<5,np.nan,df.ali)
    ali mali tresholholded
0   1   4   NaN
1   2   2   NaN
2   3   6   NaN
3   4   4   NaN
4   5   5   5.0
5   6   6   6.0
6   7   10  7.0
```